# pandas dataframe sum date range of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. I want to sum an "amount" column in the 2nd, for each record in the first datafame.

So for each

```
df1.Date = sum(df2.amount WHERE df1.Date <= df2.Date AND df1.yearAgo >= df2.Date)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2018-10-31','2018-10-30','2018-10-29','2018-10-28'],'yearAgo':['2017-10-31','2017-10-30','2017-10-29','2017-10-28']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2018-10-30','2018-7-30','2018-4-30','2018-1-30','2017-10-30'],'amount':[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.75]})
```

desired results:

```
df1.Date     yearToDateTotalAmount
2018-10-31        3.0
2018-10-30        4.75
2018-10-29        3.75
2018-10-28        3.75
```

Comment: Are you sure shouldn't be `4` in your first row in desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, your expected output should have `4` in first row.

You can achieve this very efficiently using `numpy`'s feature of [`outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) comparison, since `less_equal` and `greater_equal` are `ufunc`s.

Notice that

```
>>> np.greater_equal.outer(df1.Date, df2.Date)

array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True]])
```

So you can get your mask by

```
mask = np.greater_equal.outer(df1.Date, df2.Date) & 
       np.less_equal.outer(df1.yearAgo, df2.Date)
```

And use [`outer multiplication`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) + summing along `axis=1`

```
>>> np.sum(np.multiply(mask, df2.amount.values), axis=1)

Out[49]:
array([4.  , 4.75, 3.75, 3.75])
```

In the end, just assign back

```
>>> df1['yearToDateTotalAmount'] = np.sum(np.multiply(mask, df2.amount.values), axis=1)

    Date        yearAgo     yearToDateTotalAmount
0   2018-10-31  2017-10-31  4.00
1   2018-10-30  2017-10-30  4.75
2   2018-10-29  2017-10-29  3.75
3   2018-10-28  2017-10-28  3.75
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! Yes, the first expected value should be 4, I got a bit sloppy trying to cobble together a simple example. One question though, maybe I’m blind, but I don’t see where the “v.values” is coming from.

Comment: @Ethan sorry, `v.values` is `df2.amount.values`. ;)

Comment: No worries at all, I was just getting my head out and coming to the same answer! Thanks a million, this has been driving me a bit crazy. P.S. my wife thanks you, too!